# Записать COOKIE на сайте для другого домена

Tags: php, javascript

Есть файл go.php, в котром стоит перенаправление на другой сайт.

```
header("location: http://site.com");
```

Как в этом файле сделать запись в COOKIE пользователя, чтобы значение сохранилось и можно было вывести javascript'ом на сайте куда идёт перенаправление.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя устанавливать куки для разных доменов. Можно, например, отослать нужные вам данные GET параметрами:

```
header("location: http://site.com?token=gKFtykgkVGHvghvhg&skin=black");
```